# single-column revtex4-1 adds a page break after the title section

Tags: page-breaking, titles, revtex

Using `revtex4-1` in single-column mode produces a page break after the abstract.  This is not the behavior with `revtex4`.  The minimal example is really simple:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\title{Some stupid title}
\maketitle
The body of the paper goes here.
\end{document}
```

Adding author, abstract, whatever, doesn't make any difference.  The result is two pages, where the title is on page 1, but the text is on page 2.  Just switching the documentclass back to `revtex4` gives me a single page, as expected.  What's going on?

I've updated my entire installation through `texlive (2010)`, and have

```
revtex4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r
```

Looking at the APS website, this looks like it's the most recent version.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it). You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed in `revtex4-2`.  The [Author's Guide](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/doc/auguide/auguide4-2.pdf) says

> The `onecolumn` option no longer defaults to creating a separate title page.

And indeed, changing to `\documentclass{revtex4-2}` in the MWE posted above results in a single-page document.

Answer (score 55):

By default, `revtex4-1` reserves a whole page to typeset the title and the author(s) information; to change this behaviour, you need to use the `notitlepage` class option:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{revtex4-1}
```

Comment: Beautiful!  That works perfectly.  I just wish that had been noted more prominently in the documentation.  It also seems like a backwards default IMO.  Especially because that's not the behavior with the twocolumn documentclass option.  Anyway, thanks very much.

Comment: I also had to remove certain styles like `pop` and `preprint`

Comment: this is a beautiful answer +1