# preprint REVTeX 4.1 moves the body on the second page

Tags: revtex

This is a follow-up to [single-column revtex4-1 adds a page break after the title section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19057/single-column-revtex4-1-adds-a-page-break-after-the-title-section/42455#42455)

I was looking to make the body come right after the abstract. But the solution posted there (insert the option `[notitlepage]` to the document class) does not solve the issue for me: I also need to add the options

```
[aip, preprint, jmp]
```

or at least `[preprint]` option and maybe this interferes. I edit my document in TeXmacs, under TeX Live 2011 Version 0.92 (0.92), mac 5.8.

Could you help, or do you think this is normal?

Comment: This is the correct behaviour as far as I know. Preprints are meant to be nicely spaced out so that notes can be written on them.

Comment: Out of interest, why is the preprint option necessary?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt : hi Mark, when submitting for the first time to an American Physics Society's journal (j. math. physics my case), for the review purpose, they require a preprint option. That's what they say in their intructions/guides. But thanks for your opinion. I will submit even with such a behaviour if I don't get other answers soon.

Comment: Do not alter this behaviour. That's exactly as they want it. This is for review purposes. In any case, they will re-typeset the document.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep: Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour as far as I know. Preprints are meant to be nicely spaced out so that notes can be written on them. Unless you have a very good reason to change this behaviour, I strongly advise you to keep it as it is. It's exactly as they want it. This is for review purposes. In any case, they will re-typeset the document.